# Function to rotate player with mouse position is based on mouse distance instead of position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed an answer on the Unity Forums on how to rotate an object according to the position of the mouse. The code works for changing the rotation, but it uses some other parameter to rotate the object, as you can see in this recording.

[image]

Here is my code for the mouse detection and position editing (from `Game.cs`'s `update()` function:

```
playerLocation = PlayerScript.position;
playerRotation = PlayerScript.rotation;
mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

mousePosition.z = 5.23f;
Vector3 objectPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (playerLocation);
mousePosition.x = mousePosition.x - playerLocation.x;
mousePosition.y = mousePosition.y - playerLocation.y;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePosition.y, mousePosition.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
playerRotation = new Vector3(0f, 0f, angle);
```

Here is the code for the position applying (from `PlayerScript.cs`'s `update()` function.:

```
playerLocation = PlayerScript.position;
playerRotation = PlayerScript.rotation;
mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

mousePosition.z = 5.23f;
Vector3 objectPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (playerLocation);
mousePosition.x = mousePosition.x - playerLocation.x;
mousePosition.y = mousePosition.y - playerLocation.y;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePosition.y, mousePosition.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
playerRotation = new Vector3(0f, 0f, angle);
```

If you need any more information, please comment it.

Comment: What is wrong here? Seeing as there is a picture and not a recording I don't understand what is wrong. I'm unable to test  the code at this second but it looks alright from here, assuming the player variables are the correct things. What do you mean it uses some other param to rotate?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'll try to reupload the GIF, hold on...

Comment: There you are I reuploaded

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/DerekCresswell/GameDesign11/blob/master/3%20Top%20Down%20Arcade/3%20Health.md#rotating-towards-the-player) is a link to a tutorial I've made, perhaps try out this method for now, replacing `player.transform` with your mouse point. As I say I'm not able to use Unity until tomorrow. Ping me if you really want your and I'll give it a go then. I should also say it's worrying if you have that code twice, there should be one instance of updating the player's rotation on the player really.

Comment: Using your tutorial, I get the error ```'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'transformDirection' and no accessible extension method``` whenever I try to use ```transform.transformDirection(Vector3.up)```

Comment: In your case, it should "look" like `player.transform.transformDirection(Vector3.up)`, perhaps checkout [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/585035/lookat-2d-equivalent-.html) thread also.

Comment: Were you able to get this working or would you like me to provide a different method?

Comment: I would like a different method. Even in the player controller script, it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things, you seem to imply that there you have this code on two different objects. You should create a single script called "LookAtMouse". Whatever you put this on if what will look at the mouse.

```cs
public Camera cam;
void Update() {

  Vector3 direction = Input.mousePosition - cam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
  float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
  transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);

}
```

So this should be only on the player.

Comment: I tried this but I get the compiler error ```'Camera' does not contain a definition for 'WorldPointToScreen' and no accessible extension method 'WorldPointToScreen' accepting a first argument of type 'Camera' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)```

Comment: Hmm, guess it's [WorldToScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html) these days. Also make sure you set the camera variable. Updated answer.

Comment: That works perfectly! Is there a way I can edit the angle? I would like to have the sprite be at its normal rotation when the mouse is below it, instead of on the right of it.

Comment: If this works please mark it as the answer :)  `angle` should be between 0 and 360, if the mouse is below that angle would be `>  180` and you could manually set the rotation in the same fashion as above but give it a value of `0`, if I'm reading that right.