# Is there a way to rotate only on the Z axis Unity2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D game and I want my projectile to rotate only on the z-axis. Currently, it rotates on all 3 axes and the sprite is twisting around.

```
GameObject fireGO = Instantiate(fireball, transform.position, transform.rotation);
fireGO.transform.right = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - fireGO.transform.right;
```

And then the rotation code for the fireball:

```
transform.position += transform.right * sped * Time.deltaTime;
```

Comment: The `visual-studio` tag is reserved for questions about Visual Studio itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to rotate player with mouse position is based on mouse distance instead of position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500082/function-to-rotate-player-with-mouse-position-is-based-on-mouse-distance-instead)

Comment: @DerekC. It worked really well. Thanks for helping me out!